# generating pdf files from excel sheet using xml and windows forms

Tags: c#, xml, excel, winforms, pdf-generation

I need to develop a windows forms application that generates pdf files from excel sheet data .the mapping of data from the excel sheet to the controls in pdf should be done using a xml file.A pdf file has to be generated for each row of the excel sheet at the click of a button.How is this done?

Comment: Search for iTextSharp. You could develop a PDF template with a grid and fill in the cells or create the PDF on the fly (a lot of work would be my guess.)

Comment: @rheitzman i have a pdf template already .how do you fill in the specific fields in the pdf with values from the excel sheet row?and it has to be done for each row..

Comment: My "answer" below should help. You'll have to create the code to read the Excel rows, match the Excel columns to PDF Field names, and call the provide routine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library routine that use a Dictionary of field names and values to populated a PDF template. For your case you would need to create the dictionary from your Excel row data mapping the data properly into the field names (case sensitive) in the template. You do not need to fill in "missing" fields unless you want to insert defaults.

The project will need a reference to itextsharp. The itextsharp.dll needs to be copied to the output directory.

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Import System.IO
Public Function FillPDFForm(PDF_MasterPath As String, Flds As Dictionary(Of String, String), Optional PDF_FinalPath As String = "", Optional FlattenForm As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    ' case matters: Dictionary Keys == PDF Form Field Names
    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields
    Dim pdfReader As PdfReader
    Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper

    Try
        If PDF_FinalPath = "" Then PDF_FinalPath = PDF_MasterPath.Replace(".pdf", "_Out.pdf")
        Dim newFile As String = PDF_FinalPath

        pdfReader = New PdfReader(PDF_MasterPath)
        pdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create))
        pdfReader.Close()
        pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

        For Each sKVP As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Flds
            pdfFormFields.SetField(sKVP.Key, sKVP.Value)
        Next

        ' flatten the form to remove editing options?
        ' set it to false to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
        If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
            ' leave in editable state
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False
        Else
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = FlattenForm
        End If

        pdfStamper.Close()

        Process.Start(newFile)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        pdfStamper = Nothing
        pdfReader = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Here's some code to harvest the form field names from a PDF form:

```
Private Function PDFFieldNames(pdfPath As String) As String
    Try
        Dim s As String = ""

        ' create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
        Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(pdfPath)

        Dim fields As IDictionary(Of String, iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item) = pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
        For Each key As String In fields.Keys
            's = "pdfFormFields.SetField(""{fname}"", Row!{fname})".Replace("{fname}", key)
            s &= key & "|"
        Next
        pdfReader.Close()
        Return s
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```